# How to find and replace text in the Visio file by .Net programming

Tags: .net, vb.net, visio

I need to create a lot of flowchart which use templates like below.
[image]

Each flowchart changes "TABLE_NAME" label.

Finally, each flowchart was exported to be image(.PNG)

```
Private Sub CreateFlowChartVisio(ByVal TemplateFilename As String, ByVal saveAs As Object)
   Dim vApp As Visio.Application
   Dim vDoc As Visio.Document       
   vApp = New Visio.Application()        
   vDoc = vApp.Documents.OpenEx(TemplateFilename, 4)

  ''///Code for replace TABLE_NAME likes below code''//
   vDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="*TABLE_NAME*", ReplaceWith:=screenTitle & " Master", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

   For Each p As Visio.Page In vDoc.Pages
       Dim n As String = saveAs
       p.Export(n)
   Next
   vDoc.Close()
End Sub
```

I tried to use the *Replace* function like in *Word* application

```
vDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="*TABLE_NAME*", ReplaceWith:=screenTitle & " Master", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use the Replace function like in Word application

```
    vDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="*TABLE_NAME*", ReplaceWith:=screenTitle & " Master", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

> But this isn't working.

no doubt, because each shape have own text property. you must iterate all shapes on page. and iterate all pages in your document
and ms word's method dont works in ms visio. VBA macro for this task

```
Dim p as Page
Dim shp as Shape
For each p in vDoc.Pages  
For Each shp In p.Shapes
   shp.Characters.Text = Replace(shp.Characters.Text, "TABLE_NAME", screenTitle & " Master")
Next shp
p.export(n)
Next p
```